# Share common many-to-many table based on differentiator

Tags: postgresql, prisma

I have a `Tag`, `User` and `Role` entities. I want `User` and `Role` to have tags. Instead of creating 2 (or **n**) many-to-many tables supporting that, I want to create a single table that hosts all tag relations and differentiates them by entity type. Here is an example:

| id | entity-type | entity-id | tag-id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | user | 240 | 14 |
| 2 | role | 32 | 9 |
| 3 | role | 32 | 14 |

Where `entity-type` is the differentiator and `entity-id` is the id of the specific entity. The question is, how (if possible) can I represent this in a prisma model? So, any `User` should have relation to all tags from the many-to-many table **that are of `entity-type` = `user`** and have the appropriate id.

```
model User {
 id       String @id
 username String 
 tags     Tag[]
}
```

```
model Role {
 id   String @id
 name String 
 tags Tag[]
}
```

```
model Tag {
 id         String @id
 name       String 
 entityType String

 @unique([name, entityType])
}
```

```
model TagsOnTypes {
    entityType   String         @map("entity-type")
    entityID     String         @map("entity-id")
    // relation?

    tagID        String         @map("tag-id")
    tag          Tag            @relation(fields: [tagID], references: [id]) //?

    @@id([entityType, entityID, tagID])
}
```